# convert curl command to ajax request / javascript query

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

I tried to convert curl command in screenshot to ajax request and error returned is message indicate that there is invalid parameters

[image]

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.rrrrr.com/v1/authorization/token",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader('emaxa', 'rOXFkGeerg87jL6D');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Password', 'rOXFttyueg87jL6D');
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: '{"grant_type":"client_credentials"}',
  processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Not enough information given in question

Comment: the error returned is message indicate that there is invalid parameters

Comment: But you have to set username and password as parameters not as headers. After you receive the token, you will send it via headers.